# UIWebView respond to "Dynamic Type", iPad's text size settings

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ipad, cordova, uiwebview, dynamic-text

I have a embedded Cordova UIWebView within an iOS app. I have used bootstrap for to make the html pages responsive. Now i want to make the text on the web view respond to the dynamic text size settings of iPad. I have tried using "-apple-system-font", but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Know this is really late, but this has been working for me. You may want to use `-apple-system-body` rather than `-apple-system-font`. There's a number of font choices that can be found on the [What's New in Safari](https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_7_0.html) page.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-mobile-accessibility (text zoom)?